# jQuery - trying to do a function inside an if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, if-statement

I'm trying to add some validation to a form.  I have a jQuery function that is doing exactly what I want:

```
      jQuery('#post').submit(function() {
                if (jQuery("#set-post-thumbnail").find('img').size() > 0) {
                    jQuery('#ajax-loading').hide();
                    jQuery('#publish').removeClass('button-primary-disabled');
                    return true;
                }else{
                    alert("Please set a Featured Image!");
                    jQuery('#ajax-loading').hide();
                    jQuery('#publish').addClass('button-primary-disabled');
                    return false;
                }
                return false;
            });
```

However, I want to change it so that this function only runs if a radio button elsewhere on the page is selected.  So I tried this:

```
if (jQuery('#top').checked) {
      jQuery('#post').submit(function() {
                if (jQuery("#set-post-thumbnail").find('img').size() > 0) {
                    jQuery('#ajax-loading').hide();
                    jQuery('#publish').removeClass('button-primary-disabled');
                    return true;
                }else{
                    alert("Please set a Featured Image!");
                    jQuery('#ajax-loading').hide();
                    jQuery('#publish').addClass('button-primary-disabled');
                    return false;
                }
                return false;
            });
    }
```

That doesn't work - the function doesn't get called even if #top is checked.  Can anyone explain why?  I'm used to PHP, and JavaScript often throws curveballs at me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does firebug or Chrome console tell you? You could try something like this:

```
$('#top').is(':checked')
```

as in (thanks RET):

```
jQuery('#post').submit(function() {
  if ($('#top').is(':checked')) {
    if (jQuery("#set-post-thumbnail").find('img').size() > 0) {
      jQuery('#ajax-loading').hide();
      jQuery('#publish').removeClass('button-primary-disabled');
      return true;
    }else{
      alert("Please set a Featured Image!");
      jQuery('#ajax-loading').hide();
      jQuery('#publish').addClass('button-primary-disabled');
      return false;
    }
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: since the `if statement` returns, you do not need to wrap the next section in `else statement` and `return false` twice

Comment: It still just doesn't do anything... Firebug doesn't give me any errors or anything either.

Comment: Ah hah!  This did actually solve it!  I had to replace the $ with jQuery (this is a WordPress site, and WordPress is really picky about that).  Thanks so much, RET, Roy, and Greener!

Answer (score 0):

try

`$('#top').is(':checked')`

but the function submit only binds the function and calls it every time submit is clicked.
so you must put the checked check in the submit function

```
  jQuery('#post').submit(function() {

            if(!$('top').is(':checked')){ return };

            if (jQuery("#set-post-thumbnail").find('img').size() > 0) {
                jQuery('#ajax-loading').hide();
                jQuery('#publish').removeClass('button-primary-disabled');
                return true;
            }

            alert("Please set a Featured Image!");
            jQuery('#ajax-loading').hide();
            jQuery('#publish').addClass('button-primary-disabled');
            return false;

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that logic won't quite do what you're hoping for. Try something like:

```
  jQuery('#post').submit(function() {
      if ($('#top').is(':checked')) {
            // all your existing code
```

I could be wrong, but I don't think the answer given by @greener is going to work, because that will only declare the submit function if `#top` is checked at page create time.

Comment: The accepted answer by @greener has been corrected, so ignore comment above.